# How to show remote notification for duration of 2 minutes in iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working on Emergency Type app . our requirement is show notification an play emergency sound for 3 minutes  when we receive remote notification . i am able to do this when my app is `running` or `suspended` . but when app is `not-running`  the notification show only for few seconds.

Is there any way to show the notification for  2 minutes , when we receive remote notification. i have searched a lot but didn't find any way to do this , in ios app .
This is payload for notification :

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Enter your message","badge":1,"sound":"pushAlert.mp3"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible because this is default behavior and you can't change it! I mean you can not show notification with your custom time or you can not play long sound for the notification as it restricts to the `30 seconds`. check the [Apple Doc says](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW10) ,

> Custom sounds must be under 30 seconds when played. If a custom sound is over that limit, the default system sound is played instead.